# Why does the pivot work in a nested select but not on a single select?

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

The following works

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMP VIEW events_pivot AS
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT user_id user, event_name 
  FROM events )
  PIVOT (
    count(*) FOR event_name IN
  ("cart", "pillows", "login", "main", "careers", "guest", "faq", "down", "warranty", "finalize", 
  "register", "shipping_info", "checkout", "mattresses", "add_item", "press", "email_coupon", 
  "cc_info", "foam", "reviews", "original", "delivery", "premium")
  )
```

but if I change the statement to just

```sql
SELECT user_id user, event_name 
  FROM events
  PIVOT (
    count(*) FOR event_name IN
  ("cart", "pillows", "login", "main", "careers", "guest", "faq", "down", "warranty", "finalize", 
  "register", "shipping_info", "checkout", "mattresses", "add_item", "press", "email_coupon", 
  "cc_info", "foam", "reviews", "original", "delivery", "premium")
```

I get the following error back

```
[UNRESOLVED_COLUMN.WITH_SUGGESTION] A column or function parameter with name `event_name` cannot be resolved. Did you mean one of the following?
```

Im confused as to what seems to be operating differently between the solo select vs when it is nested, as in both cases, the output appears to produce the same resultant table of a user and event_name column before a pivot would be operated onto it.

Answer (score 1):

PIVOT result do not contains column `event_name`.

There columns `cart`,`pillows`,`login` an so on.
This is actually the purpose of the PIVOT operation.

```
SELECT user_id user, event_name -- <-- no column event_name - this is error
  FROM events
  PIVOT (
    count(*) FOR event_name IN
  ("cart", "pillows", "login", "main", "careers", "guest", "faq", "down", "warranty", "finalize", 
  "register", "shipping_info", "checkout", "mattresses", "add_item", "press", "email_coupon", 
  "cc_info", "foam", "reviews", "original", "delivery", "premium")
```

You can write

```
select *
FROM events
PIVOT(...)
```

Or any set or all columns from the list

```
select user_id,cart, pillows, login, main, careers, guest, faq, down
FROM events
PIVOT(...)
```

By the way, in the first case you also cannot write

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMP VIEW events_pivot AS
SELECT user_id user, event_name  FROM ...
```